# Vertical tangents at discontinuous points from Thomas' Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

This question is from Thomas' Calculus 12th edition page126 , Q35 and Q36.

> Does the graph of
>
> $\;f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{, if }x>0\\0&\mbox{, if }x=0\\-1&\mbox{, if }x<0\end{cases}$
>
> have a vertical tangent at the origin ?

> Does the graph of
>
> $\;U(x)=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{, if }x \geq0\\0&\mbox{, if }x<0\end{cases}$
>
> have a vertical tangent at the point (0,1) ?

According to the book , a continuous curve $y=f(x)$ has a vertical tangent at the point where $x=x_0 $ if its derivative at this point is equal to $+ \infty$ or $- \infty$

When i  check for the answer ,  i saw two different opinion in slader.com , one of the answers say that there is not any vertical tangent for both of the functions , because they are not continuous at given points. The other answer says that $f(x)$ has vertical tangent but $U(x)$ not.

I thought that there is not any vertical tangent for both of the functions because of discontinuity. What do you think about them ?Do they have vertical tangent or not ?

Comment: I would say, since your definition is for continuous curves and both examples are discontinuous, they don’t have vertical tangents…

Comment: If we're not worrying about whether the function is continuous, and not worrying about some specific author's definition of "vertical tangent", then each function has at $x=0$ a right derivative of $+\infty$ and a left derivative of $+\infty,$ and thus each function has a two-sided derivative of $+\infty$ at $x=0.$ Regarding whether they have a vertical tangent at $x=0,$ I agree with @PrudiiArca. Personally, I think the the author wants to include exercises like this, then the definition of "vertical tangent" should have been more carefully worded. As presently worded, **(continued)**

Comment: it is not clear whether non-continuous curves can also have a vertical tangent (surely we would want to allow this when the vertical tangent is at a point of continuity and the discontinuities of the curve are at other points -- you'd probably also want the points of discontinuity bounded away from the point in question), and it is not clear whether the restriction to continuous curves is just for the definition of "vertical tangent of a continuous curve" (and a separate definition might apply to discontinuous curves) or the notion of "vertical tangent" ONLY applies to continuous curves.

Comment: *(Too late to correct an oversight in my first comment!)* Ooops! The second function has at $x=0$ a right derivative of $0$ and a left derivative of $+\infty,$ and thus there is no two-sided finite or infinite derivative at $x=0.$ (Draw a rough sketch, put your finger ON the point $(0,f(0)),$ and consider the slopes of line segments with this point as one endpoint and the other endpoint on the graph and on the appropriate side, with the other endpoint approaching where your finger is.) Also, the first "the" in *I think the the author wants to include exercises like this* should be "if".